# Noob stopped the Windows Firewall service in Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

Any way to start it back up or regain access remotely?  We don't have anyone onsite as the server is collocated in another state.  Obviously they shouldn't have done what they did, and I'm just trying to get access back.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like somebody stopped more than just the Windows Firewall service.

At this point, you need to have somebody onsite to bring services back online. No real workaround there.

Comment: I've seen this a bunch of times. I can't tell if it's new "features" in Windows 2008 or if a lot of people are just pushing it out via their Policies.

Comment: @Rilindo Disabling Windows Firewall in Vista/Server 2008 or later disables RDP (and various other remote capabilities) due to Windows Filtering Platform as per https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766337%28WS.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 3):

**This assumes your policy doesn't drop ALL network traffic of course**

Do you have powershell installed? If so:

```
Get-WMIObject -computer WKLEGWEBSRVFP01 Win32_Service -Filter "Name='Windows Firewall'" |Start-Service
```

should do the trick.

If not, try the sc command. I don't have a Windows 2008 box handy so I don't know the actual service name, but if you do

```
sc \\<servername> query
```

You'll get a list of services. Find whatever windows firewall actual service name is and execute

```
sc \\<servername> start <firewall service>
```

Comment: sc doesn't work if Windows Firewall is disabled on Vista/Server 2008 or later as RPC is uncontactable.

Comment: Same with wmi...